# Displaying Tabular Data In A WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, html-table, tablelayoutpanel

I started with using a TableLayoutPanel, but when I have big tables, they are extremely sluggish.  I'm looking for the responsiveness of an HTML table to display my data in.

The only solution I currently have is to have my WinForm write and HTML table, and display it in an embedded browser.  This obviously is a huge workaround, and I'd rather implement a more clean and straightforward solution.

If you have any suggestions, please fire away. (a ListView will not work for what I'm trying to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a `DataGridView`, or if you have DevExpress, a `XtraGridControl`? TableLayoutPanel is designed for laying out controls as far as I know, not for presenting data.

On the other hand, if your data set grows as large that your tables become sluggish, you might want to narrow down your data, e.g. by filtering or by introducing paging, one page only displaying 50 items or so.

Paging as well as filtering, in turn, is supported at least by `XtraGrid`, not sure about Microsoft's `DataGridView`.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  A DataGridView is very similar to a ListView which will not work for me.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What characteristic of the `DataGridView` specifically prevents you from using it?

Comment: @Soo: It's very difficult to guess what your requirements are just by knowing that something doesn't meet them... You should be more precise about what you need.

Comment: I am at fault, I have a tendency to quickly rattle off questions while I'm at work, sorry.  I decided to embed HTML tables into my WinForm and it worked quite well for my purpose.  Thanks.

Comment: @Soo: Now I'm completely puzzled. Is that your solution? I thought it's what you wanted to stay away from? And why have you accepted my answer while commenting that you were looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need either a grid or a report, depends on what you want.

Highly customizable grid controls (like Infragistics or DevExpress) allow you to make almost any appearance you need. Users will have no idea they look at grid control.